# How to navigate from youtube notification to the specific comment under video?

Tags: youtube, firefox, windows

Is there a way to navigate from *Notifications* (bell icon at the top right corner) to the specific comment under video on youtube?

I found that I can navigate to the video if I click on the time marker when the comment received. Anyway, I have to manually look for the comment.

Is there a way to jump to it right from the Notifications strip?

My system is: Windows 10 + FireFox browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the "bell" icon () on Youtube in the top right of the page it will open your notifications, including replies, like so:
[image: screenshot of Youtube notification for comment reply]

If you click a reply it will open the thread in the notifications popup with a little badge saying "Highlighted reply", like so:

[image: screenshot of comment reply on youtube]

If you click the timestamp of that comment (in the example screenshot above it's "1 day ago") then it will bring you to the Youtube video. You do have to scroll down to load comments, but then the "Highlighted reply" will show up at the top of the comments.